# Cleaner (better) alternative to using update function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**In short:**

Is there a better way to run large functions for a long time that's less 'lagy' and memory abusive than putting it all in the update function?

**Full question**

I'm currently in the final stages of developing my first game app using iOS Swift and SpriteKit. One of the bigger problems I got is lag/delay. The Time Profiler Instrument pointed out that my `override func update` was using a lot of memory and time. My update function consists of the following:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if hasStarted {

        // Character
        updateCharacterPosition()
        updateJumpMotion()

        // Blocks
        blockRunnerDebug()

        // Wave
        debugRunningBarPosition()

        // Game Engine
        gameEngine()
        debugGameEngine()
    }

    // Update Scenery
    updateScenery()
}
```

As you can see it has a lot of functions. Most of them run background animations like water, clouds or the jumping animation of the character.

Example:

```
// Move y
        self.cloud01.position.y = self.cloud01.position.y + (CGFloat(createSinWave(0.5, b: b, angle: angle))) * 0.3
        self.cloud02.position.y = self.cloud02.position.y + (CGFloat(createSinWave(0.5, b: b, angle: angle))) * 0.3
```

**My question is: is there a better way to run large functions for a long time that's less 'lagy' and memory abusive than putting it all in the update function?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items that may change direction or position based on user interaction need to be in update. There is no way around that.

For items like background animations you can (and should) set them up once at the beginning and put them into an infinite animation loop instead of manually updating the position every update. That should help a lot.

Comment: What is the best way to do this? `SKAction.runBlock`?

Comment: Yep. It depends on exactly what you are doing if run block is 'best', but probably so. Something along the lines of:

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.runBlock(doAction)))